# ローカルで編集している js ファイルを表示しているWebページに適用できるか

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

今、フォームの入力を自動化したいと考えています。
たとえば、

```
document.getElementById('SOME_ID').value = 20;
```

のような javascript を実行すれば、該当フォームへ値を入力できることはわかったのですが、
for 文や if 文などを使い構造化していったような、手元で記述したスクリプトを今表示している Web ページに適用することはできますか？

ブラウザは、 chrome か firefox が望ましいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

今まで解答に挙がっていないので、
大抵のブラウザで使用可能な方法を追加しておきます。

ブックマークレット (Bookmarklet) という手法で、ブックマークのURLに入れても実行できます。

例えば下記コードをURLに設定したブックマークを起動すると
表示していたページ内のjavascriptとして動作してページタイトルを表示します。

```
javascript:(function(){alert(document.title);})();
```

もちろん複数の値をフォームに設定することも出来ます。

```
javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('SOME_ID').value = 20;document.getElementById('SOME_PASS').value = 30;})();
```

・解説サイト
https://support.mozilla.org/ja/kb/bookmarklets-perform-common-web-page-tasks
https://qiita.com/AQRiL_1132/items/b5f9040ccb8cbc705d04

Answer (score 1):

特定のサイト、ページに対して何かスクリプトを実行したいということであればGreasemonkeyを試してみてはどうでしょうか。

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/ - Firefox用
- https://tampermonkey.net/ - Chrome用

スクリプト(UserScript)の書き方やインストール方法はここでは省略しますが、DOM操作やHTTPリクエストなど一通りのことは実行可能です。

Answer (score 0):

Developer ToolsのConsoleにJSをコピペではだめですか？
ファイルが１ファイルならコピペでいけると思います（複数ファイルになっているとこの方法だと無理がありますが）。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]